# Posting json data to the server through android volley library not working properly

Tags: android, json

I have written a code to send a text which i type in edittext to the server through volley but it is not working properly , i am trying it for the first time using volley library after some research for faster networking calls.

I am getting an error while posting data

Code i have tried :

CustomJsonRequest.class

```
public class CustomJsonRequest extends Request<JSONArray>{

private Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener;
private Map<String, String> params;

public CustomJsonRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
    Response.Listener<JSONArray> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener 
    errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
    return params;
};

@Override
protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)  
{
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONArray response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}
```

}

Answers.class , the below method is happening on button click , i want to post jsonarray to the server

```
 private void postAnswers(){
    String answers = editAnswers.getText().toString();
    Map<String,String> answersMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    answersMap.put("answers",answers);
    jsObjRequest = new CustomJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, postAnswerUrl, 
    answersMap,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            obj.put("TransactionId", transId);
                            obj.put("UserType", userType);
                            obj.put("QId", questionId);
                            obj.put("Answer", answers);
                            obj.put("Date", date1);
                            obj.put("Time", time1);
                            obj.put("DeviceId", deviceId);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.d("Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse 
        response) {
            try {
                String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
            }
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

}
```

While i am debugging : All the values are coming properly but jsonobject request shows null

```
timeval = {String@4116} "3:43 PM"
date1 = {String@4114} "Mon, Dec 7, 2015"
time1 = {String@4116} "3:43 PM"
datetime = {String@4117} "Mon, Dec 7, 2015T3:43 PM"
transId = {String@4118} "DeviceId, Dec 7, 2015T3:43 PM"
answersMap = {HashMap@4119}  size = 1
jsObjRequest = {Write_Answers$4@4174} "[ ] http://gps.traxistar.net/PostAnswers.svc/PostAnswers 0xa3925991 NORMAL null"
```

Can anyone guide me as to where i went wrong and what changes do i need to make ?
Thank You

Comment: And what error you get?

Comment: Where do you print those debug messages?

Comment: @user BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://gps.traxistar.net/PostAnswers.svc/PostAnswers
D/Volley﹕ [1] 3.onErrorResponse: Error: null

when i debug the code , after this line 
jsObjRequest = new CustomJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, postAnswerUrl, 
    answersMap,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

it directly goes to 
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

Comment: @longwalker i dint get your question , are you asking me where i am sending those values to ?

Comment: You need to specify where exactly you have the error. And what kind of error. Please post here the error output, and which line it refers to.